# How to extract the timing and received level of spectrogram annotations manually marked in PAMguard?

Tags: whistles, pamguard, whistle-moan-detector, spectrogram-annotation

I am using the Whistle and Moan Detector (WMD) in PAMGuard to count whistles in recordings of common dolphins to quantify the whistle activity in response to simulated sonar sounds. The whistle detector is also picking up harmonics for the simulated sonar playback, but I don't want to count those in my whistle counts.

I went through and used the Spectrogram Annotation tool in PAMGuard to draw boxes around each of the sonar harmonics so that I can remove them. But now, I cannot figure out how to easily access the "list" of those annotations. I can open the PG database in a SQliteStudio and copy and paste it into a csv but I need to do this for 20+ playbacks, each with three recorders per playback so that seems inefficient.

Does anyone know of an easy way to extract these manual annotations for further processing in R or Matlab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are 3 options in R:

**(1) Use the RSQLite package**

With the `RSQLite` package it is pretty easy to read a database table into R, your table name may be different if you changed it within PAMGuard. You would then need to repeat this for every database (or loop / `lapply` through a vector of databases). You'll also probably need to convert the time columns to POSIXct depending on what you plan to do with this data.

```
library(RSQLite)
con <- dbConnect('MyDb.sqlite3', drv=SQLite())
# Your table name may be different than "Spectrogram_Annotation"
sa <- dbReadTable(con, 'Spectrogram_Annotation')
dbDisconnect(con)
```

**(2) Use the PAMmisc package**

This is actually something I've needed to do fairly often, so I wrote a function that does all this for you! `readSpecAnno` does all the steps in **(1)**, renames some of the columns to be more descriptive (ie. `f1`/`f2` -> `fmin`/`fmax`), and converts date columns to `POSIXct` as well as adding an `end` for each row instead of `UTC` and `Duration`. The nice part of having this all in a single function is that it is really easy run it on multiple databases and combine the result.

```
library(PAMmisc)
# Again, your table name may be different
sa <- readSpecAnno('MyDb.sqlite3', table='Spectrogram_Annotation')
# Easy to run on lots and combine the results
library(dplyr)
dbList <- c('MyDb1.sqlite3', 'MyDb2.sqlite3')
allSa <- bind_rows(lapply(dbList, function(x) {
                   readSpecAnno(x, table='Spectrogram_Annotation')
}))
```

**(3) Use the PAMpal package for even more info**

The above options will only give you information contained within the spectrogram annotation table, but nothing related to the whistle contours from the detector. The `PAMpal` package can read in those whistle contours and give you additional information (min/max frequency, contour slope, and many more!). Using `PAMpal` is more involved than the other two options, but depending on your use case it can definitely be worth it.

```
library(PAMpal)
# PAMpal needs your PAMGuard database and binary files
bin <- './Binaries/'
db <- 'MyDb.sqlite3'
# Tell it which files to process, this will trigger a couple popup questions in the console
pps <- PAMpalSettings(db, bin)
# We'll use the spectrogram annotations to tell PAMpal which times we want processed
library(PAMmisc)
sa <- readSpecAnno(db, table='Spectrogram_Annotation')
data <- processPgDetections(pps, mode='time', grouping=sa, id='SpecAnnoWhistles')
```

Here `data` will have *all* detections between the start and end times of the spectrogram annotations, so to remove the harmonics we can use the `filter` function to get only frequencies within that range

```
for(i in seq_along(events(data))) {
    # get grouping info
    thisGroup <- ancillary(data[[i]])$grouping
    # Do filtering. Note fmin/max are in Hz, convert where appropriate
    data[[i]] <- filter(data[[i]],
                            freqBeg > thisGroup$fmin,
                            freqBeg < thisGroup$fmax,
                            freqEnd > thisGroup$fmin,
                            freqEnd < thisGroup$fmax,
                            UTC + duration < thisGroup$end)
}
```

More information on `PAMpal` can be found [here](https://taikisan21.github.io/PAMpal/), and a more detailed write-up with additional comments on specifically using `PAMpal` with spectrogram annotation tables can be found [here](https://taikisan21.github.io/PAMpal/CaseStudies.html).

Answer (score 4):

You can also find a suite of Matlab functions on [http://www.pamguard.org/48_MATLABRcode.html](https://www.pamguard.org/48_MATLABRcode.html). Many of the developers use Matlab for their fine-scale analysis.

The PAMGuard Matlab interface is now on GitHub at [github.com/PAMGuard](https://github.com/PAMGuard). It allows you to read detailed data into Matlab from the PAMGuard binary files. If you want data from the database, then open it with the sqlitedatabase function, however, this does need the Matlab database toolbox to be installed. If you have this toolbox, then you'll need to learn a couple of lines of SQL (lots of resources online to help with that) and you can read from the database straight into Matlab. This is a lot more efficient and a lot more reliable than going via CSV files.

Comment: @DougGillespie if you’ve got time, would you mind updating Emily’s answer with your comment using the Edit functionality? Comments can get sort of hidden in the interface over time and do best to have your valuable info in the answer itself. I can edit if you prefer.